# Split URL and Query Strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the part of a URL after the last `/` and before the querystring.

So far I had the last part of the URL, but I wasn't able to remove the querystring from the URL.

**The Javascript:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 var url = window.location.href;
 var array = url.split('/');

 var lastsegment = array[array.length-1];
 document.write(lastsegment);
</script>
```

**The structure of the URL is like this:**

`http://www.example.com/search/People?&results=latest`

I only need the `People` part. How could that be possible within the above Javascript?
Or is there any better way to do that?

Comment: this is one of the most often asked js-question i see on SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `window.location.pathname` instead of `window.location.href`. It gets only the text between the server name and the query string (which is `"/search/People"` in your case):

```
var last_part = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
```

You can read more about `pathname` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.pathname).

Answer (score 2):

Read [Window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location)

```
window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
```

[.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

Comment: The last part may not be the 3rd item of the array.

Comment: And your solution is very similar to mine.

Answer (score 2):

your code does the right thing, you could remove query strings by amending it a bit as;

```
var lastsegment = array[array.length-1];
if(lastsegment.indexOf('?'))
     lastsegment = lastsegment.split('?')[0];
```

**UPDATE:**
To handle the case if there are no query string embedded at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse an URL from another origin than `window.location` :

```
var test = 'http://www.example.com/search/People?&results=latest';

var parts = test.split('/');
lastPart = parts[parts.length-1].split('?')[0];
```

`lastPart` is now "People"